# "Unable to make the service xyz executable, aborting execution"

Tags: permissions, kde, .desktop

I am trying to integrate **[Peazip](http://www.peazip.org/peazip-linux-64.html) portable** into my [KDE](https://www.kde.org/) desktop.

I have extracted peazip portable in a path in my home directory.
I added a symbolic link to the executable by running:

```
 sudo ln -s /home/bruni/Downloads/Software/Linux/Peazip/peazip_portable-6.4.1.LINUX.x86_64.GTK2/peazip /usr/local/bin
```

I copied the included desktop integration files to

```
/home/bruni/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/
```

However, when I rightclick on a rar file in dolphin and select open with peazip. I get:

First:

> This will start the program peazip %F

And after I confirm:

> Unable to make the service PeaZip executable, aborting execution

The desktop files in `/home/bruni/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/` as well as the executable `/home/bruni/Downloads/Software/Linux/Peazip/peazip_portable-6.4.1.LINUX.x86_64.GTK2/peazip` are executable.

Any ideas?

I am running [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/) 17.04 64bit.

Comment: Why integrate a portable version? The point of portable is that you don't install it, it may be configured to just run in its downloaded directory.

Comment: @MarkKirby In the case at hand: the portable version is 64bit, the deb packages are 32bit and did not work.  I prefer the former. However, I want in any case to know the reason why this is not working.

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought you may of overlooked that.